# How to change every i-th element of an array in Modelica

Tags: arrays, modelica

I’m trying to change every i-th element of an array, as an event occurs. This could be reached by the following code. In this example every second element should be changed. Due to parameter defined array size, the second argument of the ‘inner’ loop should be set by the variable ‘Upper’.

```
model Test
  Boolean Event;
  Real Vector[6](start = ones(6), fixed = true);
  Integer Upper;
algorithm
  when Event then
    Vector := ones(6);
    Upper := 3;
    for i in {2*j for j in 1:Upper} loop
      Vector[i] := Vector[i]+1;
    end for;
  end when;
equation
  Event = if time <=1 then false else true;
end Test;
```

Dymola doesn’t accept this solution, stating ‘Failed to calculate the last argument of 1:Upper’. When I enter 3 directly instead of ‘Upper’, the code works.

Is there a possibility to fix this? Or is there an easier way to change every i-th element in algorithm section?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a Dymola issue. OpenModelica handles it just fine.
This is an alternative formulation that might work better for you (hiding everything in a function should make Dymola happier since there are no dimension sizes that are hard to deduce).

```
function incrementEveryIth
  input Real v[:];
  input Integer i;
  input Real increment := 1;
  output Real o[size(v,1)] := v;
algorithm
  o := {if mod(n,i)<>0 then v[n] else (v[n]+increment) for n in 1:size(v,1)};
end incrementEveryIth;

model Test
  Boolean Event;
  Real Vector[6](start = ones(6), each fixed = true);
algorithm
  when Event then
    Vector := incrementEveryIth(pre(Vector),2);
  end when;
equation
  Event = if time <=1 then false else true;
end Test;
```

Or perhaps this one:

```
model Test
  Boolean Event;
  Real Vector[6](start = ones(6), each fixed = true);
algorithm
  when Event then
    Vector := pre(Vector); // This should not really be needed, but OpenModelica insists
    Vector[1:2:6] := Vector[1:2:6] + {1,1,1};
  end when;
equation
  Event = if time <=1 then false else true;
end Test;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Especially the first one really works well and solved my problem.